# json volley showing error android

Tags: java, android, json, image, android-volley

```
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Patient patient = new Patient();
                            patient.setTitle(obj.getString("id"));
                            patient.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));

                            patientList.add(patient);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}
```

Logcat

```
01-07 07:27:29.294 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/MainActivity: [{"id":"g"},{"image":"http:\/\/192.168.0.101\/test\/1.png"}]
01-07 07:27:29.312 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for image
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:72)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:59)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for id
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
01-07 07:27:29.313 7938-7938/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley W/System.err:     at info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:71)
```

I can get data from the database but why does it still show that there is no value for the image?
I have checked that the url is right to get the photo. The following things are the error showed in the logcat. Please give me some helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get wrong **JSONObject** , try this

```
try {
     JSONObject objId = response.getJSONObject(0);
     JSONObject objImage = response.getJSONObject(1);
     Patient patient = new Patient();
     patient.setTitle(objId.getString("id"));
     patient.setThumbnailUrl(objImage.getString("image"));

     patientList.add(patient);

} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your response and try this

```
JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject obj1 = response.getJSONObject(1);
Patient patient = new Patient();
patient.setTitle(obj.getString("id"));  
patient.setThumbnailUrl(obj1.getString("image"));
```

Comment: Why do you need to use two jsonobjects?  Thank you

Comment: According to your response you can get ID from 0(Zero) position and Image from 1 (First postion).